# Extract the last day of the week

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to extract last day of a specific week of the year. For example the last day of the 51<sup>st</sup> week of 2013.

I need a PL/SQL Procedure/Function which can do that.

Comment: last day in a week is SUNDAY ? Sorry, I know this is silly, but still want to confirm!

Comment: what I mean exactly is that I want to extract the last day of a week.
for example: I want to know what is the last day of the 51st week of 2013, 

but first of all, you have to knwo that in Oracle the first day of all weeks starts with the first day of the year !

Comment: @oualid , yes. Actually, My context was different. Like week's first day is MONDAY or not. Ok, never mind. I have tested my solution. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: First of all you have to determine which week definition you mean. Wikipedia list several definintions: [Week numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering). Oracle supports `TRUNC(theDate, 'WW')` and `TRUNC(theDate, 'IW')`

Comment: Thank you Maheswaran Ravisankar I will use this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming **LAST DAY** in a week is **'SUNDAY'***

---

**A PL/SQL Function!**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_LAST_DATE_IN_WEEK( p_WEEK INTEGER, p_YEAR INTEGER)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_DATE DATE := NULL;
BEGIN
  IF(p_WEEK IS NULL   OR   p_YEAR IS  NULL) THEN
   -- Handle the data validation  here
    v_DATE := NULL; 
    RETURN v_DATE;
  END IF;

  v_DATE := next_day(TRUNC(to_date(p_YEAR,'YYYY'),'YYYY')+(p_WEEK-1)*7,'SUNDAY');

  IF TO_CHAR(v_DATE,'YYYY') > p_YEAR THEN
    v_DATE := LAST_DAY(to_date('12'||p_YEAR,'MMYYYY'));
  END IF;

  RETURN v_DATE;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in GET_LAST_DATE_IN_WEEK  : '||SQLERRM);
  RETURN NULL;
END GET_LAST_DATE_IN_WEEK;
/
```

**You invoke it this way!**

```
SELECT GET_LAST_DATE_IN_WEEK(51,2013) FROM DUAL;
```

*Good Luck!*

Comment: The "validation" is definitely incorrect, what happens if one of week or year is null? There's alwso no need to assign a null value to `v_date` before returning it, you've initialised the variable like that (which you didn't need to do either). Not that I understand why there's and validation. If either are null then null will be returned by your other functions, meaning that this can be considerably simplified to http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0a59/2. Although I've removed the check for something being more than a year I see no requirement to do this so I don't think this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks Ben , I corrected the null check, and agreed, the next_day() itself will do, that's the way I specified , first. You can see my edit history. Finally, if the last day of the week falls on next year, I assumed to take dec 31st of specified year, as the question stated `last day of the 51st week of 2013`

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with `dbms_scheduler`:

```
declare

   result_ date;

begin


    dbms_scheduler.evaluate_calendar_string (  
      calendar_string   => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYWEEKNO=51; BYDAY=sun',
      start_date        =>  date '2013-01-01',
      return_date_after =>  date '2013-01-01',
      next_run_date     =>  result_);

    dbms_output.put_line('  Sunday of 51st week in 2013: ' || result_);

end;
/
```